# Add end mark at the end of every article

Tags: php, functions, content

I'd like to insert an end mark like `&#128282;` 🔚 to every article I post. So I added it in `entry-content.php` like below.

```
<section class="entry-content">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'large' ); } ?>
<?php the_content(); ?><span>&#128282;</span>
</section>
```

But it failed like this...

[image]

(My default font-size is 62.5%, aka 10px)

Is there any way to make the end mark inserted to the end of the last paragraph? (Note: I prefer to add in the php file, instead of add a new function.)

P.S.: [My example post](http://chenghuayang.com/blog/2015/love-lorem-ipsum/) if you'd like to check the code.

Answer (score 0):

The end of `the_content()` is a `</p>` tag. 
It sounds like you want to include your end mark *before* that last `</p>` tag.
If so, you need a function that filters `the_content()`.

Something like:

```
function yang_end_mark( $content ) {

   $content = substr_replace($content, '<span>&#128282;</span></p>', strrpos($content, '</p>'), strlen('</p>'));

   return $content;

}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'yang_end_mark', 25 )
```

;

Comment: Thanks, I like it! But it fails. Was that because I had share button beneath the content section? (http://i.imgur.com/sIXApX8.png, some sharer code exists beneath the sharer container div.)